# Groovy Eclipse plugin not working

Tags: eclipse, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I've installed the Groovy plugin for Eclipse, but the Groovy project icon doesn't show up when I try to create a new project. There is no Groovy folder when I click "Other" either. The install process finishes without any visible problems and everything seems alright. The plugin also shows up among the installed plugins.

I'm using the 32-bit Eclipse IDE for Java Developers v3.7 on Windows Vista and the http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e3.7/ version of the Groovy plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, I installed [Springsource ToolSuite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) which comes with Groovy from the beginning but it complained that I had installed it in the Program Files directory. So I went back and installed the original Eclipse for Java Developers in my User folder and violá - it works!

Comment: This is an issue with UAC in Windows as described in the first comment at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-817.  If you extract to the root C:\ drive or some other non-UAC controlled folder, it should work.  I ended up dumping the installation in C:\IDE directory with my Eclipse installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too, and could not get it to work.  As a result, I switched to [Springsource ToolSuite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts), which has Groovy/Grails integration support and is based on the Eclipse project.

You will have to download and install several extensions to get Grails to work, though.  The setup is pretty painless.  As a complete newbie to Groovy/Grails, it took me 15 min to get started.

Netbeans 7 has a much easier Groovy plugin integration process compared to regular Eclipse if you're interested in a non-Eclipse project alternative.

Comment: I wanted to use Netbeans for Groovy, but the Apache Ivy integration is so abysmal, it should really be non-existent. I know, off-topic a bit, I guess I'm just kinda venting. :-D